# Monitoring progress of extraction job of file in a bucket?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to monitor the progress of an extraction job of a file stored in a bucket.

I've gone through the Webhooks API documentation, and if I understood everything correctly, the events only work for files stored in a folder, so it can't be used with a bucket. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So, besides polling the `GET :urn/manifest` endpoint in the Model Derivate API, and assuming the Webhooks API can't be used with a bucket, is there any other way to monitor the progress of an extraction job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webhook now supports the Model Derivative event extraction.finished. This type is exactly used in the scenario of translating model of the bucket.
This is a blog on the API. I copied it as a reference on SO:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/introducing-webhook-model-derivative-api

*Webhook now supports the Model Derivative event extraction.finished, so your app can be notified when translation job finishes. 
To use it, (1) create a hook specifying a scope.workflow:*

```
{
  "callbackUrl": "http://bf067e05.ngrok.io/callback",
  "scope": {
   "workflow": "my-workflow-id"
 }
}
```

And (2) when posting a translation job, specify the misc.workflow:

```
{
  "input": {
     "urn":  
      "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpv...."
  },
  "output": {
  "formats": [{
    "type": "obj"
  }]
 },
"misc": {
  "workflow": "my-workflow-id"
 }
}
```

With my test, the workflow can be guid of your WebHook.The post body from Forge will tell you which file is translated and its urn, location etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, it indeed works, and I stand corrected.